# imagemagick globbing multiple extensions

Tags: wildcards, imagemagick

I have a folder containing photos coming from different cameras.

I use [Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) to convert to resized **and renamed** photos in another folder.

Something like this:

```
convert "*.jpg" \
    -resize 640 -scene 1 \
    "${folder}/${prefix}_%02d.jpg"
```

The problem is some cameras save photos with "JPG" extension, others with "jpg".

To solve this I used to rename extensions with this:

```
rename .JPG .jpg *.JPG 2> /dev/null
```

**This won't work on filesystems where I have only read access. How do I glob in IM both *.jpg and *.JPG files?**

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

I got it:

```
convert "*.{jpg,JPG}" \
    -resize 640 -scene 1 \
    "${folder}/${prefix}_%02d.jpg"
```

[from here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html)